# Sveltekit Session Cookie Read / Write

Tags: cookies, svelte, session-cookies, sveltekit

I am working on an app powered by Sveltekit that provides login sessions.
When the user successfully logs in, I redirect them to their user page as follows:

```
cookies.set('session', token, {
    path: '/',
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: 'strict',
    maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30 //month
});

throw redirect(302, `/${user.login}`);
```

In the `+page.server.ts` of the user profile, I validate the session cookie as follows:

```
export const load = (async ({ params, cookies }) => {
    const session = cookies.get('session');
    if (!session) throw error(401, 'Unauthorized');

    return { "success" };
}) satisfies PageServerLoad;
```

The problem now is that the validation fails after the redirect. And only when a reload happens, the session cookie gets validated correctly. My guess is that the `cookie.set()` method is not yet executed when the redirect happens.

**Question:** The cookie validation on the `+page.server.ts` happens to fast. How to wait for the cookie to be set or otherwise how to validate the cookie later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the Svelte community over on Discord, I got my answer.

***The load function might run before the cookie is set.***

It is best to validate the cookie in the `hooks.server.js` file instead of in the load function.

A good article that I used to set up the validation:
https://dev.to/brewhousedigital/secure-authentication-in-svelte-using-hooks-k5j